# Gather date of birth of user using build-in user flows in azure b2c

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using azure b2c for IAM, in that I am using build-in user flows for signup. I have few questions.

1. I want to gather users date of birth to understand the Legal Age Group Classification. User Attributes doesn`t show the DOB in the list and if I will add it as custom attributes then it won`t be validation unless I will use custom policies.
2. I want to gather the username from the user and want to make sure it is unique as well.

I tried to create custom attribute for DOB but it can`t be validated in build-in policy. I want resolve both the problems using build-in policy only, custom policy will be last thing I want to try.

I did refer to Microsoft docs but it was not useful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-access#gather-date-of-birth-and-countryregion-data

Answer (score 1):

*I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results*

*I have the azure b2c for IAM in that I used the build-in user flow*

*I have added the DOB attributes in the user attributes as shown in below*

[image]

*Created the user flow for particular attribute*

[image]

*Make sure that we have to give the* ***Return claim*** *then only it will reflect*

[image]

*After running the user flow I am able to see the date of birth user*

[image]

*Note:*
*Make sure that we have to give the retain policy then only we can fetch the DOB details*

Comment: Thank you for your message @komali, as mentioned in question i tried the same way but in this way dob is not validated and clear text can be easily added in that.

Comment: @SpringyDeveloper Validation is not possible in the user flow, there is no option to validate, it will be possible in the custom polices only.